VS code extension function not being called
I have decide to try develop my own vs code extension
A code snippets for typescript/angular
I have my first snip Forloop.snippet
const ForLoopSnippet = 'for (let {{iterator}} = {{start}}; {{iterator}} <= {{end}}; {{iterator}} += {{step}}){//code}'



i have my extension.ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const forLoopSnippetFilePath = vscode.Uri.file('../Src/typescript/Forloop.snippet');
const forLoopSnippet = fs.readFileSync(forLoopSnippetFilePath.fsPath, 'utf8');

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    console.log("Activating for loop snippet")
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.insertForLoopSnippet', () => {
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (editor) {
            editor.insertSnippet(new vscode.SnippetString(forLoopSnippet));
            console.log("inserted")
        }
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}

and my package.json
{
  "name": "angulartypescriptexctention",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./Src/extension.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vscode": "^1.1.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7"
  },
  "contributes": {
    "keybindings": [
      {
        "command": "extension.insertForLoopSnippet",
        "key": "ctrl+shift+f",
        "mac": "cmd+shift+f",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
      }
    ]
  }
}


i have ran the extension and according to thew logs it gets activated but the snip never pops up
i have tried lots of key combos (ctrl+shift+f, ctrl+shift+l,ctrl+shift+q,ctrl+shift+o, Ect.)
also tried calling it with ctrl+shift+p and look for insertForLoopSnippet
but it isn't there
considering I'm new to this I'm probably just overlooking something
Some times is says activating extension but nothing happens

For one thing, you register the command in 2 places.  You don't need it in your Forloop.snippet file.

Hi @Mark thanks for letting me know i have removed it but still the same issue

i have moved to using json for mat for snippets and it works now with out even registering events


